# I can't build C++ with visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want compile my "hello world" with C++ but I can't.
I use Visual Studio Code and here's my code.

When I try to build cpp, the error is:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/a1/C++/first'

my file is " /Users/a1/C++/first.cpp "

This is for macOS, High Sierra 10.14, and Visual studio code.

I installed C/C++ but now I can't build my C++.

```
#include "stadfx.h"
#include < iostream >

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
std::cout <<"Hello, World" <<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

> Executing task: g++ /Users/a1/C++/first.cpp -o -g /Users/a1/C++/first <

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/a1/C++/first'
터미널 프로세스가 종료 코드 1(으)로 종료되었습니다.

And this is my "tasks.json"

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "runner": "terminal",
  "type": "shell",
  "echoCommand": true,
  "presentation" : { "reveal": "always" },
  "tasks": [
    //C++ 컴파일
    {
      "label": "build and compile for C++",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
          "${file}",
          "-o","-g",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind":"build",
      "isDefault": true },

      //컴파일시 에러를 편집기에 반영
      //참고:   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher

      "problemMatcher": {
          "fileLocation": [
              "relative",
              "${workspaceRoot}"
          ],
          "pattern": {
              // The regular expression. 
             //Example to match: helloWorld.c:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'prinft'
              "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning error):\\s+(.*)$",
              "file": 1,
              "line": 2,
              "column": 3,
              "severity": 4,
              "message": 5
          }
      }
  },
  //C 컴파일
  {
      "label": "save and compile for C",
      "command": "gcc",
      "args": [
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind":"build",
      "isDefault": true},

      //컴파일시 에러를 편집기에 반영
      //참고:   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher

      "problemMatcher": {
          "fileLocation": [
              "relative",
              "${workspaceRoot}"
          ],
          "pattern": {
              // The regular expression. 
             //Example to match: helloWorld.c:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'prinft'
              "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning error):\\s+(.*)$",
              "file": 1,
              "line": 2,
              "column": 3,
              "severity": 4,
              "message": 5
          }
      }
  },
  // 바이너리 실행(Ubuntu)

  {

      "label": "execute",

      "command": "cd ${fileDirname} && ./${fileBasenameNoExtension}",

      "group": "test"

  }

  ]
}
```

This is my "launch.json"

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/Users/a1/C++/cpp.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb"
    }
]}
```

And this is my "c_cpp_properties.json"

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE"],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/Users/a1/C++/first.cpp",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],

"browse": {
    "path": [
        "${workspaceFolder}","/Users/a1/C++/first.cpp"
    ],
    "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
    "databaseFilename": ""
},

"version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The -o option expects a filename, which should come immediately after the "-o". You've given "-g" as the filename. And then the command ends with a file to be compiled. In your case, "first" (which doesn't exist).

Try moving the order around in your json file to something like:

```
"args": [
      "-g",
      "-o",
      "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "${file}"

  ],
```

Comment: Thanks! But I cross over new error...:C
    > Executing task: g++ -g -o /Users/a1/C++/first /Users/a1/C++/first.cpp <

    /Users/a1/C++/first.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'stadfx.h' file not found
#include "stadfx.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    터미널 프로세스가 종료 코드 1(으)로 종료되었습니다.

Comment: @심미단 These are Windows specific headers (`stdafx.h`) and macros (`_tmain` is not standard C++).  You might need to use another guide or textbook that is more universal and standards compliant.

Comment: That's a different issue. You'll need to have that file in the directory.